# Jquery loop with AJAX, looping through bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting data from database, looping trough it and appending to the div in html page. It works until I am looping trough function witch contains **bootstrap** `MODAL`. I am passing parameters to function  but every `MODAL` that was created display first row of my `database table`. My goal is to loop trough my `function(MODAL)` and pass different rows of my table, not only the first one.

VARIBLE WITH MY HTML

```
var table = {
        createTable: function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, column) {
                    $("#loopRows").append(
                        '<tr id="post"><td>' + column.ID + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + column.Title + '</td>' +
                        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details">Details</button>+showBookmark.showItemTemplate(column.Title, column.Url, column.User)+</td>'
                    });
            }
        }
```

AJAX REQUEST

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:62795/api/bookmarks',
        success: function(result) {
            table.createTable(result);
        }
    });
});
```

BOOTSTRAP MODAL WITH HTML FORM

```
var showBookmark = {
    showItemTemplate: function(title, url, user) {
        return '<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"   id="details">' +
            '<label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">   Title:' + title + '</label>' +
            '<label for="message-text" class="control-label">   Url:' + url + '</label>' +
            '<label for="message-text" class="control-label">   User:' + user + '</label>' +
            '</div>'
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving unique id to each row and when you click on particular modal button pass its id and get values of that row with the help of id. its that what you are tying to do?

Comment: try updating the last td to this `'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details">Details</button>'+showBookmark.showItemTemplate(column.Title, column.Url, column.User)+'</td>'`

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Hey  Deep Mehta. Yes, I am trying to do it. Not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Hey Sushil, that's not that's not the case. Is something more serious.